# How to convert an (char) array containing 8 bytes(which represent a 64bit int) to a string

Tags: c, type-conversion, microcontroller, iar

As written in the title, I need to convert an (char) array containing 8 bytes(which represent a 64bit int) to a string. I'm using c code on a NEC78K0R (16 bit mcu). I'm using the IAR Embedded workbench IDE.

My thought was to OR them together in a 64 bit int type (like f.x long long or int64_t (from stdint.h)), and then use something like sprintf to convert it to a string.

However the compiler will start spitting out errors like "the type 'long long' does not exist'. whenever I use any of the standard 64bit integer type.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Related topic (not entirely duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695720/how-do-i-convert-a-64bit-integer-to-a-char-array-and-back?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

If the char array references a memory block of 8 bytes that are actually a true 64-bit integer, *and* your compiler supports `int64_t`, you can just cast and dereference.

```
int64_t convert(const char* input)
{
    return *((int64_t*)input);
}
```

If the platform supports 64-bit data types, `sprintf` will also support it with the `%L` format specifier.

If your compiles does not support **any** 64-bit data types, you'll need to use a specific library to handle them for you, like [BigInt](https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/) or [GMPlib](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 0):

If `long` is the appropriate 32bit integer type and hex format would be ok, just do

```
char * p = <address of some memory containing a true 64bit number>
char s[19];
```

for a Little Endian platform:

```
sprintf(s, "0x%08x%08x, *((long*)(p+4)), *((long*)(p)));
```

for a Big Endian platform:

```
sprintf(s, "0x%08x%08x, *((long*)(p)), *((long*)(p+4)));
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the encoding of the string that you would need. The simplest would probably be to use hex encoding and just print the bytes directly.

```
printf("0x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x%02x", a[7], a[6], a[5], a[4], a[3], a[2], a[1], a[0]);
```

To make this a bit more efficient, if that is a bottleneck for you, you could just group the maximal parts that your platform supports, by casting it to an `unsigned long` e.g. But be careful if your `char` array fulfills the necessary alignment to be interpreted as such an `unsigned long`. If you can't guarantee that, you should first use `memcpy` to copy the data to a properly aligned object.

```
unsigned long b[2];
memcpy(b, a, sizeof b);
printf("0x%08x%08x", b[1], b[0]);
```

(supposing that `unsigned long` is 4 bytes)

Comment: It should be noted that the examples assume little endianess.

Comment: @alk, good remark. But as he said nothing about the representation he wanted to achieve , this one is as good as any other.