# What is Best way concatenate strings and number - Performance Using C?

Tags: c, string, performance

### Please go down and read `new/last update` section.

i very try to write a code with good performance.

but also `php interpreter script` is more fast of my `c app`.

i am test this in a big loop. and i sure then speed of my concatenate code is bad.
and sure then can make this better like php script.

---

Complate Source(c):

```
for(int count=1;count<=1000000;count++)
{
    results=str_int("New Item",count);
}
```

---

### `str_int(...)` Function :

### #1 :

```
DATA_VALUE_String *str_int(DATA_VALUE_String *s1,DATA_VALUE_Int64 s2)
{
    DATA_VALUE_String *result=malloc(sizeof(s1)+sizeof(s2)+2*sizeof(DATA_VALUE_String *));
    snprintf(result,sizeof(s2)+sizeof(s2),"%s%d",s1,s2);
    return result;
}
```

Time : `0m0.135s`

### #2 :

```
DATA_VALUE_String *str_int(DATA_VALUE_String *s1,DATA_VALUE_Int64 s2)
{
    DATA_VALUE_String *result=malloc(sizeof(s1)+sizeof(s2)+2*sizeof(DATA_VALUE_String *)); 
    DATA_VALUE_String *ss2;
    ss2=malloc((sizeof(s2)+2)*sizeof(DATA_VALUE_String *));
    sprintf(ss2,"%"PRId64,s2);
    strcat(strcpy(result,s1),ss2);
    return result;
}
```

Time : `0m0.160s`

---

But Php 7.1.4 : `0.081s`

```
<?php
//$myArrays = [];
for($count=1;$count<=1000000;$count++)
{
    $results="";
    $results="New Item".$count;
}
//unset($myArrays);
?>
```

*please help me to make this c file more fast...*

i want make my c code better.

php have more performance in concatenate string,int.
but my c code is not like them.

how can make this better?

tank you very much. :like:

=============

### New Update for Answer 1:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void int64ToChar(char **mesg, int64_t num) {
    //*mesg="..";
    *(int64_t *)mesg = num;
}
int main()
{
    int64_t num=4694;
    char *nums=malloc(6*sizeof(char *));
    int64ToChar(&nums,num);
    printf("%s",nums);
    return 0;
}
```

Error : `Segmentation fault (core dumped)`

---

### New/Last Update for Bad Performance (C vs PHP)

php(last version) : http://codepad.org/9D26wLEA

```
$ time php arrays2.php
real    0m0.089s
user    0m0.086s
sys 0m0.004s
```

---

c   : http://codepad.org/JmemaXOr

```
$ gcc arrays.c -o arrays -O3 -w
$ time ./arrays
real    0m0.131s
user    0m0.091s
sys 0m0.040s
```

How can make my `C` file better?

Comment: "please help me and not close question." , it's off-topic, you'll probably have more luck on the [code review stack exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: i just ask a question then how can make this better?!

Comment: I suspect you're using [Shlemiel's algorithm](http://wiki.c2.com/?ShlemielThePainter), maybe a `strcat()`?

Comment: mean use `strcat()` ? so how can append int to char* with `strcat()` with more performance ?

Comment: `sizeof(s1)` doesn't do waht you think it does - it returns the size of a pointer,which is not the size of the buffer you need to copy a string into.  I'm not even entirely sure what the *intent* of this expression is: `sizeof(s1)+sizeof(s2)+2*sizeof(DATA_VALUE_String *)`.   Before you worry about performance too much, make sure the code is correct.

Comment: @michael-burr , what is better way to `malloc()` `char *`? may say me  change to what!?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to concatenate strings in C by directly adding the second string to the end of the first string in memory via pointers.

```
 char* strConcat(char* str1,char* str2){
     while (*str1) str1++;
     do{
        *str1++ = *str2++
     }while (*str2); 
     return --str1; //return a pointer to the end of the new string
 }
```

This returns a pointer to the end of the new concatenated string so you can just pass the pointer along to continue to concatenate to this current string. Alternately, if no further concatenation is necessary, you can maintain the pointer to the head of the concatenated string.

Comment: tank you . how can append int to string with more performance?

Comment: I think this function is more efficient than strcat, however, you will need to test if the conversion from int64 to char* will cause it to be worse than the methods you have tried. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695720/how-do-i-convert-a-64bit-integer-to-a-char-array-and-back

Comment: ```#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void int64ToChar(char **mesg, int64_t num) {
 //*mesg="..";
 *(int64_t *)mesg = num;
}
int main()
{
 int64_t num=4694;
 char *nums=malloc(6*sizeof(char *));
 int64ToChar(&nums,num);
 printf("%s",nums);
 return 0;
}```   ==========>Error : Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: Q: are you sure then your strConcat() function support utf-8 unicode?

Answer (score 0):

Someone gave an algorithm much faster than snprintf for converting an int to a string :
[How to convert an int to string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257714/how-to-convert-an-int-to-string-in-c)

This algo (I named it xitoa below) is also faster than the PHP script.
(I tested with int32, rather than int64, but it illustrates a significant improvement over snprintf)

My benchmark:

- with snprintf: 1.54s
- with xitoa: 0.99s
- with PHP: 1.23s

These results were obtained with gcc optimization -O2 (for snprintf and xitoa).

Here is the algo that I tested (copied from the given link):

```
char * xitoa (int value, char *buffer, int base)
{
    // check that the base if valid
    if (base < 2 || base > 36) { *buffer = '\0'; return buffer; }

    char* ptr = buffer, *ptr1 = buffer, tmp_char;
    int tmp_value;

    do {
        tmp_value = value;
        value /= base;
        *ptr++ = "zyxwvutsrqponmlkjihgfedcba9876543210123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" [35 + (tmp_value - value * base)];
    } while ( value );

    // Apply negative sign
    if (tmp_value < 0) *ptr++ = '-';
    *ptr-- = '\0';

    // reverse the characters, as they were stored less-significant first
    while (ptr1 < ptr) {
        tmp_char = *ptr;
        *ptr--= *ptr1;
        *ptr1++ = tmp_char;
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

Comment: Q: are you sure `xitoa()` support `utf-8` ?

Comment: Q: `-O3` not better of `-O2` ?

Comment: may say a sample code then how can use from this function?

Comment: `char str[5];printf("%s\n",  xitoa(15,str,2) );` , output is : `1111`

Comment: why output is `1111` ?

Comment: Output is 1111 because you convert 15 which is decimal (base 10) to binary (base 2) as you specified in your third parameter.

Comment: tank you , can make another function for convert `long double` to string? @Sterls

Comment: are you sure then with `xitoa()` have more speed?                                c : http://codepad.org/JmemaXOr               php : http://codepad.org/9D26wLEA     , i test this and php have more speed. @Sterls