# uint64_t to an array - C language

Tags: c, arrays, uint64, itoa

I tried to parse uint64_t array to an array of char (result in decimal, separated by comma).

I used memcpy, every time I get a random values. iota() function converts max uint32_t values. I tried separate uint64_t to 2 uint32_t, but I never get a right result.

```
    uint64_t numbers[10] = { 201234567890123456, 
                           12345678901234567890, 
                           98765432109876543, 
                           65432109887, 
                           12345234512345,
                           217631276371261627,
                           12354123512453124,
                           2163521442531,
                           2341232142132321,
                           1233432112 };
    char array[1000] = "";
```

Expected result:

```
array = "201234567890123456,12345678901234567890,98765432109876543,65432109887,12345234512345,217631276371261627,12354123512453124,2163521442531,2341232142132321,1233432112"
```

I tried int64ToChar from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695720/how-do-i-convert-a-64bit-integer-to-a-char-array-and-back) topic, but result is:

```
    void uint64ToChar(char a[], int64_t n) {
         memcpy(a, &n, 10);
    }

    uint64_t number = 12345678900987654;
    char output[30] = "";

    uint64ToChar(output, number);

    Result:
    �g]T�+
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: You want to print the representation of a number using ascii characters in base 10. Use `snprintf`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I convert a 64bit integer to a char array and back?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9695720/how-do-i-convert-a-64bit-integer-to-a-char-array-and-back)

Comment: It would help if you showed the code that you tried.

Comment: @Papooch: I don't think the suggested Q&A is very helpful.  I'm not convinced by the answers I see, either.

Comment: Your `uint64_t` array initialisation won't work like that: it needs braces around the `={` data `};`.

Comment: P.S. the sixth element in your array `21763127637126371627` is larger than a 64 bit unsigned integer. Use a smaller number.

Answer (score 2):

Ue `snpintf()` to convert the 64-bit numbers:

```c
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main() {
    uint64_t numbers[10] = { 201234567890123456, 
                             12345678901234567890, 
                             98765432109876543, 
                             65432109887, 
                             12345234512345,
                             21763127637126371627,
                             12354123512453124,
                             2163521442531,
                             2341232142132321,
                             1233432112 };
    char array[1000];
    size_t i, n = sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]), pos = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < n && pos < sizeof(array); i++) {
        pos += snprintf(array + pos, sizeof(array) - pos, "%"PRIu64"%s", numbers[i],
                        i < n - 1 ? "," : "");
    }
    printf("%s\n", array);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @KamilCuk: Yes Indeed! Answer amended. I keep wondering why these macros are not defined in `<stdint.h>`.

Comment: Thanks, It helped me a little bit. On PC it works well. I compiled this code for embedded platform (ESP-IDF) and I my result is : lulululululululululululululululululu... and so on.

Comment: @maghost: Your platform seems to have conformity issues. Try changing `"%"PRIu64"%s", numbers[i],` to `"%llu%s", (unsigned long long)numbers[i],` or possibly `"%lu%s", (unsigned long)numbers[i],`

Comment: @maghost: if you use the Arduino C platform, be aware that this C variant has substantial differences from C, including subtle shortcomings in its standard library.

Comment: I don't use an Arduino platform, but I use ESP-RTOS-SDK for ESP8266. I found the issue - newlib library is in "nano" version (for stack and heap optimalization), which don't support u64 as printf functions, The "normal" version crashes when I used NVS partition with it. Maybe there is some other way except snprintf?

Comment: @maghost: you can write your own 64-bit to decimal conversion routine.

Answer (score 2):

If all the data is available at compile-time, there's no obvious reason why you should use slow run-time conversion functions like s*printf. Simply do it all at pre-processor stage:

```
#define INIT_LIST           \
  201234567890123456,       \
  12345678901234567890,     \
  98765432109876543,        \
  65432109887,              \
  12345234512345,           \
  217631276371261627,       \
  12354123512453124,        \
  2163521442531,            \
  2341232142132321,         \
  1233432112

#define STR_(...) #__VA_ARGS__
#define STR(x) STR_(x)

int main (void)
{
  uint64_t numbers[10] = { INIT_LIST };
  char array[] = STR(INIT_LIST);
  puts(array);
}
```

More advanced alternatives with "X macros" are possible, if you want to micro-manage comma and space placement between numbers etc.

Please note that `12345678901234567890` is too large to be a valid signed integer constant on my 64 bit system, the max is `2^63 - 1` = `9.22*10^18` but this number is `12.34*10^18`. I have to change it to `12345678901234567890ull` to get this program to compile, since the maximum number is then `18.44*10^18`.

Comment: Thanks for hint, but data isn't known at compile time. Only for that this is an variable array of numbers, not const.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using `sprintf_s` in a `for` loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFSIZE 22                  /* string buffer size to support a single 64 bit unsigned integer */
#define ARRSIZE 10                  /* size of the unsigned integer array */
#define STRSIZE BUFSIZE * ARRSIZE   /* max size of the string of unsigned integer array */

int main()
{
    int i;
    char num_str[STRSIZE] = "";
    uint64_t num_arr[ARRSIZE] = {
        201234567890123456,
        12345678901234567890,
        98765432109876543,
        65432109887,
        12345234512345,
        2176312763712637162,
        12354123512453124,
        2163521442531,
        2341232142132321,
        1233432112
    };

    for (i = 0; i < ARRSIZE; i++)
    {
        /* convert an unsigned integer to a string and concatenate to previous string every loop */
        sprintf_s(num_str + strlen(num_str), BUFSIZE, "%llu,", num_arr[i]);
    }

    num_str[strlen(num_str) - 1] = 0;   /* truncate the trailing comma */

    printf("%s", num_str);

    return 0;
}
```

This results in:

```
num_str = "201234567890123456,12345678901234567890,98765432109876543,65432109887,12345234512345,2176312763712637162,12354123512453124,2163521442531,2341232142132321,1233432112"
```

Comment: Why use `sprintf_s` if you are going to pass an incorrect size argument?

Comment: Thanks, It helped me a little bit. I changed sprintf_s -> snprintf() because I work on Linux. On PC it works well.

I compiled this code for embedded platform (ESP-IDF) and I my result is :

lu,lu,lu,lu,lu,lu,lu,lu,lu,lu

Answer (score 1):

The `memcpy` function copies byte by byte from one location to another.  What you're attempting to do is take 10 bytes of a 64 bit number (which only contains 8 bytes) and reinterpret each of them as an ASCII character.  Not only will this not give the results you expect, but you also invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) by reading past the memory bounds of an object.

Guessing at what functions do is a *bad* way to learn C.  You need to read the documentation for these functions (run "man function_name" on Linux for the function in question or search learn.microsoft.com for MSVC) to understand what they do.

If you use the `sprintf` function, you can convert a 64 bit integer to a string.  The `%lld` identifier accepts a `long long int`, which is at least as big as a `uint64_t`.

```
sprintf(a, "%lld", (unsigned long long)n);
```

Comment: Technically, `unsigned long long` can represent all 64-bit values, but for complete portability you should either cast the `uint64_t` argument as `sprintf(a, "%llu", (unsigned long long)n);` or use the C99 formatting macros: `sprintf(a, "%"PRIu64"", n);`